# Get codename of android device

Tags: android

How can I get the device specific codename?

For example:

- nexus 5 > **hammerhead**
- OnePlus One > **bacon**

I searched already in the `android.os.Build` constants. The `build.prop` file contains a property called ro.build.NAME, which is (in my case) `bacon`. But there is not an `android.os.Build.NAME` constant. Where can i get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it:

```
android.os.Build.HARDWARE
```

Comment: This also worked when I tried on Google Pixel XL (I got `marlin`), but when I tried with Samsung Galaxy S8 I got `samsungexynos8895`, but expected `dreamlte`. That codename I however got from the solution posted by @JaredRummler

Answer (score 2):

You should get the value of "ro.build.product". This is how you should get the codename of a device:

```
public static String getCodename() {
    String value = Build.DEVICE;
    try {
        final Class<?> sp = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        final Method get = sp.getMethod("get", String.class);
        value = (String) get.invoke(null, "ro.build.product");
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks JRummy ;) but `android.os.Build.HARDWARE` is easier to use, isn't it?

Comment: I guess it depends what you are using it for. If you are building an app that has to do with the device's codename (what CyanogenMod, ClockworkMod, and other root related apps use) then you should use the above code. If it is for another project, use Build.HARDWARE or whatever works for you.